# Difference between 'ls' and 'echo $(ls)'

Tags: shell

Consider the two shell samples

```
$ ls
myDoc.html
SomeDirectory
someDoc.txt
```

and

```
$ echo $(ls)
myDoc.html SomeDirectory someDoc.txt
```

The first executes `ls` which, as I understand, appends the contents of the current working directory to the `stdout` file (which is what the terminal displays).  Is this correct?

The second takes the value of the `ls` command (which means is the contents of the current working directory) and prints it to the `stdout` file. Is this correct?

Why do the two commands give different outputs?

Comment: because you are doing echo. The output of ls as input to echo command.

Comment: This is "expected" behaviour, which someone will explain shortly. However, are you sure that `ls` by itself doesn't give you multiple items per line?

Comment: @roaima columnized ls is a remnant of a bsd "feature". unix versions print one entry per line

Comment: @SteveCox I haven't used proper UNIX since early SVR4 so my memory's a little hazy. Thank you for the reminder.

Comment: Why not `echo *`?

Answer (score 84):

When you run this command:

```
ls
```

the terminal displays the output of `ls`.

When you run this command:

```
echo $(ls)
```

the shell captures the output of `$(ls)` and performs [*word splitting*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) on it.  With the default `IFS`, this means that all sequences of white space, *including* newline characters, are replaced by a single blank. That is why the output of `echo $(ls)` appears on one line.

For an advanced discussion of word splitting, see [Greg's FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting).

#### Suppressing word splitting

The shell does not perform word splitting on strings in quotes.  Thus, you can suppress word splitting and retain the multiline output with:

```
echo "$(ls)"
```

#### `ls` and multiline output

You may have noticed that `ls` sometimes prints more than one file per line:

```
$ ls
file1  file2  file3  file4  file5  file6
```

This is the default when the output of `ls` goes to a terminal.  When the output is not going directly to a terminal, `ls` changes its default to one file per line:

```
$ echo "$(ls)"
file1
file2
file3
file4
file5
file6
```

This behavior is documented in `man ls`.

#### Another subtlety: command substitution and trailing newlines

`$(...)` is *command substitution* and the shell removes trailing newline characters from output of *command substitution*.  This normally is not noticeable because, by default, `echo` adds one newline to the end of its output.  So, if you lose one newline from the end of `$(...)` and you gain one from `echo`, there is no change.  If, however, the output of your command ends with *2 or more* newline characters while `echo` adds back only one, your output will be missing one or more newlines.  As an example, we can use `printf` to generate trailing newline characters.  Note that both of the following commands, despite the different number of newlines, produce the same output of one blank line:

```
$ echo "$(printf "\n")"

$ echo "$(printf "\n\n\n\n\n")"

$
```

This behavior is documented in `man bash`.

#### Another surprise: pathname expansion, twice

Let's create three files:

```
$ touch 'file?' file1 file2
```

Observe the difference between `ls file?` and `echo $(ls file?)`:

```
$ ls file?
file?  file1  file2
$ echo $(ls file?)
file? file1 file2 file1 file2
```

In the case of `echo $(ls file?)`, the file glob `file?` is expanded **twice**, causing the file names `file1` and `file2` to appear twice in the output.  This is because, as Jeffiekins points out, *pathname expansion* is performed first by the shell before `ls` is run and then again before `echo` is run.

The second *pathname expansion* can be suppressed if we used double-quotes:

```
$ echo "$(ls file?)"
file?
file1
file2
```

Comment: additionally, using `isatty` you can check if stdout is a tty, ls uses this to determine whether to use colors or not.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: bash also has the `-t` test operator for that. (from man page: *`-t fd`  True if file descriptor `fd` is open and refers to a terminal.*)

Comment: Aren't the quotes mismatched in the last code snippet? Or do `$( )` actually provide a syntax barrier so you needn't interpolate?

Comment: @cat `$()` provides a syntax barrier.

Comment: One more important difference: if any filename contains a wildcard character, the `echo` command will *expand the wildcard*.  For example, if `ls` returns **file? file1 file2**, then `echo $(ls)` will return **file? file1 file2 file1 file2**.

Comment: @Jeffiekins Interesting suggestion. I just added a discussion of that to the answer.

Comment: @Jeffiekins `echo` does not expand wildcards; the shell does before passing the resulting expansion as arguments to `echo`.

Comment: @chepner You are, of course, correct.  I just figured, from the question, that *exactly who* does the expansion was more likely to confuse than to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

`ls` is aware if it is sending output to a terminal or not.

Executing `ls` at a command prompt will write to your pseudo-tty. Redirecting the output of `ls` will generally *not* be going to a pseudo-tty, and `ls` will format the output differently.