# Print only certain columns while maintaining white space

Tags: bash, awk, columns, whitespace

I have some code that prints select columns from the output of `lsblk`. However, the spacing in the result makes it hard to read. Is there anyway to do this while maintaining the white space?

```
echo "`sudo lsblk | awk -F ' ' '{print $1 "  " $4 "  " $6 "  " $7}'`"
```

output:

```
NAME  SIZE  TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda  238.5G  disk
├─sda5  68.6G  part  /
├─sda6  7.8G  part  [SWAP]
└─sda8  1000M  part
```

Comment: Can't you just do `sudo lsblk -o name,size,type,mountpoint`?

Comment: Yep, that totally works, can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks so much @steeldriver

Comment: @steeldriver Add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use `printf` and assign column widths yourself:

```
lsblk | awk '{printf "%-8s %8s %5s %s\n",$1,$4,$6,$7}'
```

You may freely adjust the column widths in the `printf` statement to fit your needs.

Example:

```
$ lsblk | awk '{printf "%-8s %8s %5s %s\n",$1,$4,$6,$7}'
NAME         SIZE  TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda        500.0G  disk 
├─sda1       100M  part /boot
├─sda2      28.6G  part /
```

#### Aside

Consider the form as shown in the question:

```
echo "`cmd1 | cmd2`"
```

versus the form:

```
cmd1 | cmd2
```

While both forms are similar, the subtle differences between these two are discussed in depth [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283586/difference-between-ls-and-echo-ls/283589#283589).  Usually, the later form provides fewer surprises.

Comment: Note that it would still break the device tree if it had several levels like in the example in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here, you can tell `lsblk` to output the columns you want in the first place:

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME                 SIZE TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                465.8G disk
├─sda1                 1G part
└─sda2             464.8G part
  ├─VG_XY-debian64    40G lvm  /
  ├─VG_XY-swap        16G lvm  [SWAP]
  └─VG_XY-home       300G lvm  /home
sr0                 1024M rom
```

Answer (score 0):

@John1024's answer and @steeldriver's comment are perfectsolutions.

Alternatively fix the previously obtained output

```
...your_command | column -t
```

Comment: That would also break the device tree if it had several levels like in the example in my answer and would left-align instead of right-aligne the size (see also the MAJ:MIN column that is aligned on the colon which would complicate matters if on wanted that column included). This solution has the advantage of not hard-coding the maximum length of the device path.