# What is the difference between (*) and (“$(ls)”)?

Tags: bash, ls, wildcards, array

What is the difference between `(*)` and `("$(ls)")`?

Are they essentially the same except the delimiters are different?

Comment: Are the parenthesis part of the command?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Yes. This means that they are arrays.

Comment: There is some relevant information here: [Difference between 'ls' and 'echo $(ls)'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283586/difference-between-ls-and-echo-ls/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one, `(*)`, globs the list of files and directories in the current directory and creates a list. You can assign that list to an array variable, and each file name will be its own entry.

```
touch 'a b' c
d=(*)
printf "> %s <\n" "${d[@]}"
> a b <
> c <
```

The second one, `(“$(ls)”)`, invokes `ls` to list the current directory. The resulting list of files and directories is put into a single string and assigned to a list. The list contains this single element consisting of the newline-separated set of names.

```
d=("$(ls)")
printf "> %s <\n" "${d[@]}"
> a b
c <
```

The first one is better as the file names are posted properly into individual elements of the list, and parsing the output of `ls` is often fraught with unexpected complications

Comment: Very good answer.  For those new to shell programming, I would just add that anything, like `("$(ls)")`, that involves parsing the output of `ls` generally considered to be [an abomination](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).