# Does Bash perform word splitting when capturing command resuls?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Foreword: I've already seen possibly related question [Difference between 'ls' and 'echo $(ls)'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283586/difference-between-ls-and-echo-ls)

Does bash perform word splitting on output capturing? This guide -- mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting says "no":

> Word splitting is not performed on expansions in assignments. Thus, one does not need to quote anything in a command like these: [...] `bar=$(a command)`

But when I do `res=$(find); echo $res` output differs from just `find`:

```
$ find
.
./file2
./file1
./test.sh
$ res="$(find)"; echo $res
. ./file2 ./file1 ./test.sh
$ res=$(find); echo $res
. ./file2 ./file1 ./test.sh
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce with `GNU bash, version 5.0.18(1)-release (x86_64-slackware-linux-gnu)`

Comment: The the text that you quote does not apply to the output that you see, which is produced by `echo`.  You may want to try `echo "$res"`.

Comment: @thanasisp sorry, I found out that firstly I used zsh as a shell :-D

Comment: In that case, could you please clarify you question with that information, and possibly rephrase it?

Comment: @Kusalananda ok, I will try to rephrase question

Comment: When `bash` processes an unquoted variable reference (e.g. `echo $res`), it'll word-split the result (assuming default options). zsh does not do this (again assuming default options).

Comment: @GordonDavisson does bash perform word splitting on output capturing? This guide -- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting says "no", but when I do `res=$(find); echo $res` it differs from just `find`

Comment: @Kusalananda I've updated the question

Comment: @The splitting doesn't happen in `res=$(find)`, but it does in `echo $res`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023461/when-should-i-double-quote-a-parameter-expansion) and its answer. Personally, I think it's easier to just double-quote all variable and command substitutions, rather than trying to keep track of where it's safe to omit the quotes and where it can cause trouble.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the text that you quote only relates to the assignment to your variable `res`. There is no issue with that part.

The `find` utility produces newline-delimited pathnames as output, as you show.

Assigning this output to a variable will retain the newlines (except for the last, which is removed).

It's all good so far, but then...

When you call `echo` with your unquoted variable in `bash`, the variable's value is split on spaces, tabs and newlines (by default), and the resulting strings undergo filename generation (globbing).  The resulting words are then given as individual arguments to `echo`.

The `echo` utility will output its arguments delimited by space characters (and add a newline at the end).  This is what you show happens with `echo $res`.

To see the value of the variable without letting the shell split it into multiple words and do filename globbing on them, double quote the variable's expansion: `echo "$res"`, or even better, `printf '%s\n' "$res"` (see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)).

In short, the expansion of the variable in the call to `echo` must be quoted.